# How to replace a certain number with that many X's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, ecmascript-6

I work at a dealership and Im moving our sales board onto a screen. We use to every time we sell something, we add a X to the board. but now I want to make it simple for my managers to use so I want something like:

This is what I tried

```
$('#salesperson_tbody').append(`
        <tr>
            <td>${i.name}</td>
            <td>${i.cars_sold.replace('[0-9]', 'X')}</td>
        </tr>
 `);

function salesperson(name,cars_sold) {
    this.name = name`
    this.cars_sold = cars_sold;
};

const Steve = new salesperson(
    'Steve',
    '9.5',
);
```

but the 9.5 is XXXXXXXXX/. I dont want to replace cars.sold but have a function that replaces the 9.5 for the X's on display. So my manager can input 10 and instead of showing 10 on the screen it has 10 X's.

Answer (score 0):

If a full star is `X` and half `/`, then it's quite simple:

```js
$("#button").on("click", () => {
  const stars = parseFloat($("#stars").val());
  if (stars % 1) {
    $("#results").text(`${"X".repeat(Math.floor(stars))}/`);
  } else {
    $("#results").text(`${"X".repeat(stars)}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="stars" min="0" max="10" step="0.5">
<button id="button">See Stars!</button>
<p id="results"></p>
```